# How to get alert message when a play button is clicked in jwplayer 5?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am working on omniture site catalyst variables to be placed for video tracking for a client. My problem is when we click on jwplayer play button i want to throw a alert message. Can anybody please advise me how to do this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick sample!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
            file: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4",
            image: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.jpg",
            flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
            height: 300,
            width: 465,
            events:{
                onPlay: function(event) {
                    alert('Playing!');
                }
            }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am using this player in a product that was developed in php and mysql. It is developed based on mvc architecture so the code what you gave me already in one class, but when i made necessary changes to that class i am not getting any alert message. Is there anyother way or this is the only one way

Comment: You are going to have to provide some sort of example here of what you are trying to do here. I gave you a simple example how events working in the player, which indeed works, and also answers your original question.

Comment: Thank you very much for that Ethan Long tail but the problem is i am working on Client developed product called Prism so i have to decide whether the code is to be displayed here or not. Please give sometime to think

Comment: Okay, understood. We definitely can't guess as to why it isn't working without code or a link though.

Comment: hey Ethan my issue is solved thank you very much for your help if i need any further development for this question i will add the content here. Once again thanks a lot and lot